# Batik SVG to PNG with included xhtml

Tags: svg, batik

I'm using Batik (1.8) to convert SVGs to PNGs within my plugin. One of my clients has a SVG (snipped see below) which uses XHTML for text elements inside the SVG. Those text elements are not shown in the rasterized PNG.

Further details: obviously Batik evaluates the required feature (extensibility) as true and then tries to handle the XHTML part - it does not use the fall back outside the foreignObject. The handling of the XHTML part is however not successful as no text is shown. No exceptions etc. are thrown. The code used is pretty much the standard code as shown in the Batik examples. Any ideas what I can do to make Batik show that text?

Thank you for any hints,

Andreas

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300px" height="167px" version="1.1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<defs/>
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><rect x="1" y="47" width="120" height="60" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="3 3" pointer-events="none"/>
<g transform="translate(49.5,70.5)">
<switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="22" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 24px; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: normal; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Test</div></div></foreignObject><text x="11" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">Test</text></switch></g>
</g></svg>
```

Comment: Batik is an SVG renderer, it does not support HTML. If you want to display text you'll need to display SVG text

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your answer. Should Batik then not fall back to the given SVG alternative given in my example above?

Comment: No, the feature string you're using just means supports the foreignObject element itself. It does not mandate support for any particular contents within the foreignObject element.

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a way to include foreignObject for the browsers which can handle this and at the same time include svg-text for the renderer's which can't render foreignObject ?
We have exactly the same problem here. Generating SVG's which shall be rendered in chrome/firefox (supporting foreignObject) as well as IE11/apache-batik (not supporting foreignObject).